# Specifying separate config file on mysqldump command line

Tags: mysql

My main MySQL user's /home//my.cnf file looks like this (Linux system):

```
[client]
host=localhost
user=<user>
password=********
database=h2o_amr
```

I want to point mysqldump to this config file, which is in the directory where the mysqldump file will be written:

```
[client]
host=localhost
user=<user>
password=********
```

How do I point mysqldump to this config file? I have searched for an answer to this in the man pages and the Internet before posting this question.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

There are three options to change the default behavior:

- `--no-defaults`: Don't read default options from any option file.
- `--defaults-file=#`: Only read default options from the given file #.
- `--defaults-extra-file=#`: Read this file after the global files are read.

This information was copied from the integrated manual, i.e.
`mysqldump --help | grep -A7 'Default options'`.

**Note**: The parameter needs to be in first position if you add others parameters, if not it will not be recognized.

Answer (score 2):

[According to the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/option-files.html#option_general_defaults-file), there is a `--defaults-file=PATH` option that does exactly what you need. I tried it myself with mysqldump and it appears to have worked.

There are also other ways to have MySQL read option files without using that argument: using the default paths MySQL clients search through to compile the list of options ([1st and 2nd table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/option-files.html)).