# Can I have multiple [mysqldump] sections in ~/.my.cnf?

Tags: mysql, credentials

After reading the answers on [MYSQLDUMP without the password prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9293042/802365) I was wondering :

> Is it possible to store multiple credentials, to different db accounts, in one `~/.my.cnf` file? If so, what is the syntax?

**N.B.:** I reckon that could rise **security issues** but that's strictly for local/dev environment.

Answer (score 7):

Asking on IRC #mysql here is what I got:

> MrAmmon | not really, no.  You can, if you like, have multiple files
>   and reference them, though MrAmmon | example - mysql
>   --defaults-file=~/.my.cnf-bobby

### Solution

1. Create a **credentials file for your project** ;
2. **Reference it** when doing the dump (`--defaults-file=` [must be the first option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3836471/802365)):

```sh
mysqldump --defaults-file="$HOME/.my.project.cnf" -u projectUser --no-create-db --no-create-info projectDb
```

### Others options

There is [several argument to control options](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10725590/802365):

> ```
> --no-defaults: Don't read default options from any option file.
> --defaults-file=#: Only read default options from the given file #.
> --defaults-extra-file=#: Read this file after the global files are read.
> ```